# How to execute mysql_fetch_row() upon a button click

Tags: php

I am tying to put some user data from the database using php. 
The database contains so many record and i am displaying it using `mysql_fetch_row()` and this gives me the fields of first row.

Now the problem is a have two buttons namely next and previous. And when a click next the fields in the next row has to be obtained the they should be inserted into page without loading the page once again. I am facing problem with this.

I am using php for server side programming and html, css for client side programming.

Comment: You could load it all into the DOM, hide irellevant records, and show as you require using jQuery(JavaScript).  You could also look into using AJAX - again jQuery makes this easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that no one will give you the answer. Too many to write. You need to read about ajax (this is the technology that will allow you to do some action without page reloading).

You need to write javascript(you can use some library like jquery) function which will open some php page with the data that you want and then update your site.

Here you have some nice tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp